# Multiple Background Images - Need just the one to cover

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have two background images. The first is a picture of some trees which I want at the back and the other is just a black box that I want to hover over the top of the tree picture.

The problem i'm having is that when I use the 'background size: cover' style it messes them both up. I just need the tree picture to cover and the box to sit on top. Here's the code:

```
    .main-image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 370px;
        background: url('../img/main-img-black.png'), url('../img/main-img.jpg') ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-position: 10,0;
        background-size: 1, cover;  
    }
```

I hope this sort of makes sense!

Comment: background-size: auto, cover;, just throwing an idea in

Answer (score 1):

[Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) `background-size: 1, cover;` is not valid CSS, so the rule 'falls over'.

Try changing it to:

`background-size: 10px, cover;`.

If you arent setting the value to `cover`, `contain`, `auto` or zero- the number must be followed by the unit type.

Comment: When I try that, the box thhat I need floating on top disappears

Comment: @user3087394 - you'll need to change the 10px to whatever suits for your purposes, or use `auto`: Demo http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/TbEF8/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it, thanks to the suggestions. Everyone was right about the background-size unit.
Here's the working code:

```
.main-image {
width: 100%;
height: 370px;
background: url('../img/main-img-black.png'), url('../img/main-img.jpg') ;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-position: center;,0;
background-size: 700px, cover;
```

}